# How to center dmath equation under an item?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, breqn

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\eqinterlinepenalty=0
\intereqpenalty=0 

\begin{document}

    \blindtext[3]

    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item
        \begin{dmath*}
        1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        \end{dmath*}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

And I get a equation not centered under item.

Any solution to force the centering of the equation under item with dmath?

**Requirement:** the equation will break accross pages

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

The itemize environment changes the left margin, so I offset the equation the same amount in the first bullet.  In the second bullet, I incremented the indent a further amount `\itemsep`, which is the space between the bullet and the item text.  One of those two solutions should give you a satisfactory answer.  In the third bullet, I show how long those lengths are, to convince you of their value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item
        \begin{dmath*}
        \rule{\leftmargin}{0in} 1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        \end{dmath*}

        \item  Line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item
        \begin{dmath*}
        \rule{\leftmargin+\itemsep}{0in} 1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        \end{dmath*}

       \item x\rule{\itemsep}{0in}x\rule{\leftmargin}{0in}x
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

SUPPLEMENT:

As barbara beeton points out, there appears to be a slight discrepancy in the alignment, that I had not seen at first.  I have confirmed that it arises when the line gets close to full textwidth.  Furthermore, it seems to have nothing to do with the `\rule` that I had added as part of my original solution, but rather with dmath itself!  See below, where no rules are added.

In the first instance, outside of itemize, the equation formats well. In the second instance, inside the itemize, it also formats well.  In the third instance, inside itemize, the addition of a few extra characters produces the non-alignment barbara notes.  But the deal breaker is the fourth instance.  OUTSIDE of itemize, when the equation approaches full line width, the same non-alignment arises.  This last case clearly has nothing to do with itemize, nor does it have anything to do with `\rule`s.  It is a problem in `dmath` itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

        \begin{dmath*}
        xxx1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        \end{dmath*}


    \begin{itemize}
        \item  Line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item
        \begin{dmath*}
        xxx1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        \end{dmath*}

        \item  Line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item
        \begin{dmath*}
        xxx1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        \end{dmath*}


    \end{itemize}

        \begin{dmath*}
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
        \end{dmath*}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: are my eyes going, or are those equal signs really not lined up?  the first one in each group looks slightly to the left of the others.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Now that I put on my glasses, I see your point

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please see my supplemental response.  The problem appears to be with dmath.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- this slight discrepancy may have to do with the (known) idiosyncrasy with the alignments implemented in `amsmath`, namely that they all start the aligned lines with a thinspace (`\,`).  i'll take a look at the innards of the macro definitions when i get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to place the display in a minipage:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of
  item, line of item, line of item, with minipage:\par
  \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \begin{dmath*}
      1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 +
      1 - 1 + 1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
    \end{dmath*}
  \end{minipage}
\item Line of item, line of item, line of item, line of item, line of
  item, line of item, line of item, no minipage:
  \begin{dmath*}
      1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 +
      1 - 1 + 1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1
  \end{dmath*}
\item Another item.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you do not need to know which indentation variables are being used.  However, the equation will not break across pages (even with `\allowdisplaybreaks`), and the vertical spacing around the equation is noy completely standard.