# Problems in breqn package

Tags: breqn

I use XeLaTeX and while using the `breqn` package, although it breaks the equations in multiple lines I get badboxes. Why is that happening? The package isn't breaking automatically and correctly the equations? How can I fix it? Also if I load the `unicode-math` before the `breqn` I get errors but if I load it after it I get weird results:

This is without the `unicode-math` and with badboxes:

[image]

and this is with the `unicode-math` and without badboxes:

[image]

The code I used is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.3in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\3}{\vspace{0.3cm}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^{k}
= f(c)+f’(c)(x-c) +\frac{f’’(c)}{2!}(x-c)^{2}
+ \frac{f^{(3)}(c)}{3!}(x-c)^{3}+\cdots
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Also if I use this code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
e^{jz}=\cos z+j\sin z
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath*}
\cos z=(1/2)(2\cos z)=(1/2)(2\cos z+j\sin z-j\sin z)=(1/2)(\cos z+j\sin z+\cos z-j\sin z)=(1/2)(e^{jz}+e^{-jz})
\end{dmath*}
\end{dgroup*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

it doesn't break the equation at all except if I remove the `unicode-math`:

[image]

One more thing is that in these cases there was plenty of room so there was no need to "break" the equations just yet. Why did it do it anyway? What is going on here?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I use XeLaTeX.

Comment: Some more breqn woes, at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119811/how-to-center-dmath-equation-under-an-item

Comment: I'm quite certain that `breqn` doesn't work with `unicode-math`, because they fight over the same constructions. My own experience tells me that `breqn` doesn't do what it's supposed to; others may think differently.